# How to declare variable in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table:

Id  Name   Count

1   Apple  1

2   Peach  1

If I just have Name and MySql which is set to "Safe Update Mode"(under this mode, can't update table with out key in where terms). So I need get Id by Name at first, then update row.

In SqlServer, I can do it like below:

```
DELCARE @Id INT;
SELECT @Id=(SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Name='Apple')

IF(@Id IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  UPDATE MyTable
    SET Count=2
  WHERE Id=@Id
END
```

In MySql, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) keyword to declare the variable, but you don't really need it.

```
UPDATE MyTable 
    SET Count=2
  WHERE ID IN ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE name = 'Apple') S)
```

This isn't the most efficient in the world, but it functions as a work-around when the update query depends on the table it's updating.